# List All videos from facebook Profile

Tags: javascript, facebook

Sorry if this question was asked before or is a duplicate, but i cant seem to find any existing plugin that would list all the videos from my profile. All i can find are the manual procedures where i have to copy the embed code and paste where i want it, but i need a plugin that could take a user profile link or token and list all videos under it, there is a `Graph API` i came across but that too provides uploading videos and photos and retrieving user profile only, could not find any link in the documentation that would list the videos or maybe i overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

The API call would be `/me/videos`, example code is in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#Reading):

Example in the API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fvideos&version=v2.10

Of course you need to authorize the user with the `user_videos` permission.